# why this error "list index out of bound"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to find greatest in a sequence?

```
k=[10,7,5,9,2]
def gr(k):
    i=0
    j=1
    for x in k:
        if k[i]>k[j]:
            x=k[i]
            j+=1
        else:
            x=k[j]
            i+=1
    print x
```

why putting the largest no. at the first position in the list is giving index out of bound error , otherwise it is running perfectly.I know various other methods to do this like max and all but i want to correct this.

Comment: You are changing the value of the looping variable `x` in the middle of a loop, which is never a good idea. Also give meaningful variable names, so that your intentions become clearer.

Comment: Reinventing `max()`?

Comment: NOPE! just figuring out how it works.

Comment: See my updated answer for a small additional challenge on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's concentrate on what was asked:

> Why putting the largest no. at the first position in the list is giving index out of bound error , otherwise it is running perfectly?

The answer is quite simple:

The indices `i`, `j` are at start `0` and `1`. If the first item in the list is the largest, for each item in the list `j` is increased by one what results in index out of bound for the last item in the list.

If the largest item is not the first one `j` will be increased by one maximal `n-1` times where `n` is the length of the list `k` and therefore the index out of bound error can't be "achieved" .

Here a fix without changing the ill "logic" of searching for a maximum using such a function instead of `max(k)`:

```
def gr(k):
    i=0
    j=1
    for x in k:
        if j > len(k)-1:
            x=k[i]
            break
        if k[i]>k[j]:
            x=k[i]
            j+=1
        else: 
            x=k[j]
            i+=1
    print (x)
```

By the way: on Stack Exchange they created for people having fun with such kind of questions https://codegolf.stackexchange.com .

We are at Stack Overflow.

Here for the sake of completeness:

> This function is NOT able to find always a maximum value in a list

what challenges the curious to find a case it returns a wrong value :)

(you can provide the "solution" to this challenge in the comments below if you like)

I am following the request in the comment to show WHEN the function above does NOT provide the right result:

> ```
> gr([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
> gr([4, 1, 7, 3, 9])
> ```

gives:

```
4
7
```

**where it should give 5 and 9 instead.**

ADDENDUM A: inspired by the postings in the comments I have a bit further improved the last in the comments provided improved version of the function, so that it now properly covers all of the possible cases:

```
def ki(k): 
    i=0
    j=1 
    y=k[j-1]
    for x in k: 
        if i > i + j: 
            y=k[i] 
            break 
        if k[j] > y: 
            y=k[j] 
            i+=2 
        else: 
            x=k[j-1] 
            i+=3
        i-=1
        j+=1
        if j > len(k)-1:
            break
    if x < x - j: 
        print(x)
    else: 
        print(y)
```

> Don't take the above serious, but don't laugh! NO humor on stackoverflow!

ADDENDUM B: Now the solution to the solution. All the above code, if you just throw away all of the statements and variables which are not necessary and **are there for the only sake of creating confusion** can be expressed as follows:

```
def ki(k): 
    y=k[0]
    for x in k[1:]: 
        if x > y: y=x 
    print(y)
```

Knowing this you recognize the actual challenge: to write code that does exactly the same as the tiny piece above but is as voluminous, as confusing and as hard to follow what it actual does as possible ...

Comment: Thanx for the solution plus the taunt.I know MAX , Reduce and various other ways to do this Mr smarty .

Comment: when we have continous series in the list.

Comment: ALREADY answered your challenge....Here is the solution to that-def gr(k):
    i=0
    j=1
    for x in k:
        if j > len(k)-1: 
            x=k[i]
            
            break
        if k[i]>=k[j]:
            x=k[i]
            y=k[j]
            j+=1
        else:
            y=k[j]
            i+=1
    if x>y:
        print x
    else:
        print y

Comment: @shivamsr. The updated code you have provided is **NOT** a solution to the problem, that the function is not able to provide proper results. It solves the problem with the first of the provided sequences, but not with the second one `gr([4, 1, 7, 3, 9])` where it still delivers **7** as wrong result. The algorithm as such is simply not suited for searching for a maximum value ...

Comment: def hr(k): 
    i=0
    j=1 
    y=k[j-1]
    for x in k: 
        
        if k[j] > y: 
            y=k[j] 
             
        else: 
            pass
            
        
        j+=1
        if j > len(k)-1:
            break
    print y

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize `j` with 1, the for loop will execute `n` times, `n` being the length of the array. Considering that the first element is the biggest, according to your code, `j` will get incremented on every iteration.

So in the last iteration, `j` will have been incremented `n - 1` times, being now equals to `n`.

Since arrays have their indices starting on 0, the valid range of indices is from 0 to `n - 1`.

Comment: can you suggest  the solution?Not changing the method.I know other methods of doing this like using Reduce function.

Comment: Your algorithm is not correct actually. Would you be able to explain why you are either incrementing either `i` OR `j`? To find the biggest number, you can simply keep track of the index of the biggest number so far. You can initialize this index with 0 for example, then iterate over the array, and whenever you find an element bigger than the one in "the index of the biggest so far", you update "the index of the biggest so far". At the end of the iteration you just return the element at "the index of the biggest so far".

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation avoids the index variables `i` and `j`.
If the sequence is empty or only contains one element, comparisons are not needed. If *n* is the length of the sequence, the number of comparisons is *n* - 1. Thus, the implementation starts the loop at the second element.

I have moved the printing outside the function.

```
k = [10, 7, 5, 9, 2]

def gr(k):
    if not k:
        return None

    if len(k) == 1:
        return k[0]

    result = k[0]
    for x in k[1:]:
        if x > result:
            result = x

    return result

print(gr(k))
```

Result:

```
10
```

BTW, this reinvents the builtin `max`.

Comment: `return k[0]` "breaks" the ill logic of the code and therefore not really the right fix ...